# How do I apply time remapping?

Tags: animation, keyframes

So, I have an animation which should be at half the speed that it originally was. So I time remapped it. But when I did this, the animation did what it was supposed to do, it played at half speed. But I wanted to animate it further at this new time-remapped speed, I came across the problem that the keyframes stayed as they originally were. So I wanted to find a way to "apply" or "bake" this new time-remapped animation. I couldn't find this anywhere, so I'm asking it here.

So my question in short,

**How do I apply the time remapped animation to the keyframes?**

Comment: I believe time remapping actually just changes the frame rate of the animation playback, so to permanently change how fast the animation runs, I would recommend selecting the key frames to be affected, and then scaling them with S. Have the time cursor at the start of the key frames that need to be scaled, as it will be used as an origin point.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the timeline, move your cursor to the first frame of the animation, select all keyframes with "A", then press "S" to scale the keyframes relative to your cursor, and then enter the scaling factor.

If you want the animation speed to be halved, scale the keyframes by 2, if you want to double the speed, scale it by 0.5 and so forth.

Comment: scaling by 2 DO indeed work BUT scaling by a fraction like  0.5 DOESN'T - the scaled frames go "empty" - I'm loosing all the    animation information - the object DOES NOT animate any more!

Comment: @Ringger81 It's probably snapping to the nearest frame (nearest "real" frame.)  Turn off frame snapping in whatever viewport you're using.